# Flutter BoxFit.cover - Show top of image, not center

Tags: flutter, image, widget

I have a cell where I have some place for an image. The height of that place is smaller than actual image height, so I use BoxFit.cover option to fit it.

Its look ok, but it shows the middle part of image, but I want to show the top of image.

**Is there any option to show top of Image when using BoxFit.cover?**

My Code:

```
  Container(
    height: 200,
    width: double.infinity,
    child: Image.network(
      appointment.imageUrl!,
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
  ),
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there is way to do so by using `alignment` property of image same as below

```
Container(
  height: 200, // set your desired height here
  child: Image.asset(
    'path/to/your/image.jpg',
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
  ),
);
```